# How to add specific library implementations in the gradle based on the build flavors

Tags: android

```
productFlavors {
    
        create("paid") {
        
            applicationId="com.paid"
            versionCode 12
            flavorDimensions "main"
      
        }
    
        create("free") {
           
            applicationId="com.free"
            versionCode 12
            flavorDimensions "main"
    
        }
    
    }
    
    dependencies {
    
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
    
        freeImplementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
        PaidImplementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:latest.release'
    
    }
```

I want to use some specific libraries that have some usage in the java classes and also in the Android Manifest. But I want to use those libraries and their usage only for a specific product flavor and not for other flavors. I couldn't find the proper solution anywhere.
I also prefre android documentation but not working my project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcyHL.png)

Comment: That's really not the best way to do things.  Generally you make 1 set of dependencies, and just enable/disable the functionality in code based on the flavor used.  That can be as easy as setting a build value in the gradle, and accessing that value in code.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan please can you add an example, I have lots of try

Answer (score 0):

If you have flavors setup like this ie:

```
 productFlavors {

        prod {

        }

        stage {

        }
    }
```

You should be able to do this:

```
stageImplementation 'your dependecy'
prodImplementation 'your dependecy'
```